# passing multiple arguments to express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a express route that looks like this:

```
    app.get('/home', function(req, res){
        res.render('chapters/home', { moment: moment });
    });
//home is an .ejs file & chapters is its folder
```

I'm using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to display dates and such, and so I need to use `{ moment: moment }` like that. But here's my problem: I have a data schema that I need to pass through this route as well.

I can't do `res.render('chapters/home', { moment: moment }, { data: data });` so I don't know how I can get around this problem.

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly is this data schema that you intend to pass through this route? Can't you do it like `res.render('chapters/home', {moment: moment, data: data})`?

Comment: It not a complicated schema..just a few string types(text, title, etc..). I haven't tried that because I thought you couldn't pass more than one obj per route.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: it worked !!thanks, man..my bad